# How to verify the response headers in Rest Assured framework

Tags: java, cucumber, rest-assured, response-headers, rest-assured-jsonpath

How to verify the response headers in Rest Assured framework? I tried the below way to check for response headers, but my code is not giving any result.

**Util file**

```
    public void verifyResponseHeaders(Map<String, String> data {
        softAssert = new SoftAssert();
        data.forEach((headers, expected) -> {
            LogUtil.log(String.format("Validating => %s", headers));
            Object actual = response.headers();
            LogUtil.log(String.format("Assertion for headers  Expected = %s; Actual = %s", headers,expected, actual));
            assertValue(actual, expected);
        });
        softAssert.assertAll();
       }
```

**Cucumber file common Step:**

```
      @And("I see headers matches for fields")
      public void verifyResponseHeaders(DataTable data) {
      apiUtil.verifyResponseHeaders(new HashMap<>(data.asMap()));
      }
```

**Login.feature**

```
 And I see headers matches for fields
 | Content-Type | application/json  |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's check with this example `curl -v https://httpbin.org/get`. As it can bee seen the headers returned are:

```
date: Fri, 26 May 2023 09:09:57 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 256
server: gunicorn/19.9.0
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
```

Let's assume also that our step receives the map like this as expected set of headers:

```java
Map<String, String> expected = Map.of(
        "content-type", "application/json",
        "access-control-allow-origin", "*"
);
```

First of all we need to convert it to a list of RA internal representation of headers:

```java
List<Header> expectedHeaders = expected
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(e ->
                new Header(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now we fetch the headers from our endpoint under test:

```java
List<Header> observedHeaders = RestAssured
        .get("https://httpbin.org/get")
        .getHeaders().asList();
```

The last thing we need to do is to decide how strict our verification has to be. If we need to check if our expected headers **are in** the actual set, then we do:

```java
assertThat(expectedHeaders, everyItem(is(in(observedHeaders))));
```

otherwise if we need to make sure the sets **are equal** (normally we do not care of item order), then we do:

```java
assertThat(observedHeaders, containsInAnyOrder(expectedHeaders));
```

Both checks utilize Hamcrest that is supplied with RestAssured transitively. So you will need to include the following imports to make assertions work:

```java
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*;
```